# Sql Server - drop synonyms from specific schema

Tags: sql-server, synonym

I would like to drop synonyms from specific schema, something like:

```
drop synonym where schema like 'my_schema'
```

or

```
drop synonym where name = my_schema.*
```

Or somethign like that?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do :

```
declare @syn nvarchar(30)
declare @temp1 nvarchar(30)
declare read_cur cursor for select distinct name from sys.synonyms where is_ms_shipped = 0

open read_cur
fetch read_cur into @syn
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
      --select read_cur into @temp1
      set @temp1='drop synonym '+@syn
      exec sp_executesql @temp1

      fetch read_cur into @syn
end
close read_cur
deallocate read_cur
```

Comment: Yes, It works for me, but to be sure I delete only synonyms from required schema I modified code to: set @temp1='drop synonym my_schema.'+ @syn
Because I don't wanna drop synonyms from another schema, just my_schema. Thanks a lot!